# IBM Worklight: Building the environment overwrites my edits

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I'm a new Worklight user. I've imported the "IncludeExternalPagesProject" in Eclipse and successfully tested it on Android.
The problem is that every time I try to edit a .java file and build the environment, it replaces the changes I made with the original version of the file. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample comes bundled with files in the nativeResources folder. Specifically for your case, the nativeResources\src\com\IncludeExternalPages .java implementation files.

The bundling was done in order to keep the application small in file size by deleting the native folder and keeping the implementation files in the nativeResources folder. What happens is that during build-time, the Worklight builder will generate the native folder and then replace the files there with the files from the nativeResources folder.

The files will be replaced on each build, which is what that is happening to you.
So what you can to do is:

1. Either delete the nativeResources folder (or just the files within) after the initial build,
2. Or put your changes in the files in the nativeResources\src\com\IncludeExternalPages folder.